# How to attach a TFT display to Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, display, touchscreen, screen, retropie

I'm trying to attach [this 7" display](http://hands.com/~lkcl/eoma/kde_tablet/HV070WX2-1E0.pdf) I took from a broken tablet. This is basically as far as I've gotten on the hardware side.

I've done a lot of research, but maybe I missed something. Anything to point me in the right direction would be helpful and thoroughly appreciated.

Also this has a touchscreen digitizer with it, but I'm not really interested in the touch input, I just want a dope display to build a RetroPie tab/laptop/portable. I'm just trying to learn how to do this, then maybe off to bigger and better.

Comment: Easy! Just write a kernel driver. Of course, if you searched this site you would discover that the hundreds of others why asked similar questions have given up.

Comment: yeah i had noticed that. thought maybe i could do it but im not really well versed, just a hobby i thought would be cool

Answer (score 1):

If you are not well versed in writing kernel drivers, I would suggest forgoing tft and simply buying at 7in hdmi screen, they can sit on top of the header pins of the pi for power and usually come with a "U" shaped hdmi plug that connects the screen to the hdmi input of the pi. In addition this still gives you the option of mirroring/rotating the image which can be useful if you plan to use the screen with a collimator for a HUD type feel for old school racing games. Usually this isn't needed but, the simplicity of using such a screen is nice and saves you the headache that many of us, myself included, have gone through in trying to find or make a kernel driver for a screen. There are already screens out there that can do what you want but they aren't cheap, and the ones that are need either special drivers or special images. Try searching this site or google for a 7in tft screen you should find plenty.

Comment: thanks for the help, i was beginning to get that picture but i really wanted to accomplish something complex without spending more money. i cant even figure out the hardware side so i think ill give up with this one. i do however have a 20 inch eetop pc that has hdmi in but the monitor osd keeps popping up. would love to be able to bypass all of that and just have a really big lcd. any ideas on this one? or is it also another straw im grasping?

Comment: Since it takes a hdmi I would imagine it should take the input in your /boot/config.txt try adding:                          #Always force HDMI output and enable HDMI sound  hdmi_force_hotplug=1  hdmi_drive=2

Comment: @JonathanEplin then make sure the HDMI is plugged in before rebooting.